# Change content of tab on button click

Tags: android, view, tabs, android-tabhost, android-intent

I have been reading a lot of comments on how it is more lightweight to use views instead of intents in `setContent` when using tabs.

Since I will be creating an app with tabs, I am trying to implement this instead of having intents inside `setContent`. However, I am having a difficult time looking for examples or straightforward tutorials on swapping the current view with another one.

<strike>Say I have TAB_A, with some entry fields and a button. When the user clicks on the button, a `TextView` will display "Hello, user!" in the same TAB_A. Of course this is an oversimplified example, but it will surely point me in the right direction.</strike>

EDIT: I have a tab called TAB_A with a button in it.  If the user clicks on that button, TAB_A will now display "Hello, user!" instead of the button.

Here is a sample of my TabSpec.

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.tabspec_tag_search))
                .setIndicator(getString(R.string.tabspec_indic_search),
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_ic_search))
                .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                   switch (doWhat){
                    case ACTIVITY_SPLASH_PAGE:
                                       return showButton;
                    case ACTIVITY_HELLO:
                                       return showHello;
                   }
                       return null;
                }
            });
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Where `ShowButton` and `ShowHello` are classes both extending `LinearLayout`.  Both are initialized in onCreate like this:
`ShowButton showButton = new ShowButton(this);`

Inside the showButton class, I have this listener:

```
viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Search247.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DO_WHAT, ACTIVITY_HELLO);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

When the app first starts, the user sees the view showButton.  When the user clicks on the button, I want the tab to change its contents to showHello.

The question then is: Is there any way to update the contents of the tabspec without using `startActivity`?

Thanks as always!

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it's not clear what your question or problem is.

Comment: I have no clue of what you want. Some code examples to create a tab screen? Our thoughts on the Intent issue? That TextView thing sure confused me.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) mView.getParent();
viewGroup.removeView(mView);
addView(showResults);
```

Where `mView` is the initial view in the tab.  Now just trying to figure out how to make the app remember to show `mView` when BACK is pressed from the new view.

Comment: great solution! i was searching it for ages..!